# Code Igniter - Controller/Model slug not returning any results

Tags: codeigniter, foreach, slug

I have a database with several entries. When I load /schedule it loads all entries correctly. However, when I try to use /schedule/state it gives me an error saying 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()' on my view. I've gotten it to work somehow (although I've apparently broken it again), but it's always thrown this error when I add the actual state to the end... ie. /schedule/state/Utah.

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong? Thank you in advance!

**View (views/schedule/state.php):**

```
<h2><?php echo $title; ?></h2>

<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
<?php

    function printDateRange($start_date, $end_date) {
        $string = "";
        if($start_date !== $end_date) {
            $string = "".date_format(date_create($start_date),"F d, Y")." - ".date_format(date_create($end_date),"F d, Y")."";
        } else {
            $string = date_format(date_create($start_date),"F d, Y");
        }
        return $string;
    }

    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($events as $event) {
        $id = $event['id'];
        $slug = $event['slug'];
        $title = $event['title'];
        $start_date = $event['start_date'];
        $end_date = $event['end_date'];
        $address = $event['address'];
        $city = $event['city'];
        $state = $event['state'];
        $country = $event['country'];
        $postal_code = $event['postal_code'];
        $image = $event['image'];
        $website = $event['website'];
        $facebook = $event['facebook'];
        $instagram = $event['instagram'];
        $twitter = $event['twitter'];
        $first_year_held = $event['first_year_held'];
        $attendance = $event['attendance'];
        $ticket_price = $event['ticket_price'];
        $description = $event['description'];

        echo "
            <div class='col-12 col-md-3'>
                <div class='schedule_box' style='width: 100%; max-width: 600px; background-color: #200080; color: #A0A0FF; padding: 10px; border: dash 1px #000; margin-bottom: 40px;'>
                    <div style='width: 100%; text-align: center; padding: 4px; color: #CCCCFF;'>
                        <h2>".$title."</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div style='width: 100%;'>
                        <img src='".$image."' style='width: 100%;'>
                    </div>
                    <div style='width: 100%; padding-top: 10px'>
                        Date: ".printDateRange($start_date, $end_date)."
                    </div>
                    <div style='width: 100%; padding-top: 10px;'>
                        ".$address."<br/>
                        ".$city.", ".$state."<br/>
                        ".$country."<br/>
                        ".$postal_code."
                    </div>
                    <div style='width: 100%; padding: 4px; text-align: center;'>
                        <a href='".$website."' style='color: #DDD;'>Visit Official Website</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ";
        $counter++;
        if($counter == 4) {
            echo "</div><div class='row'>";
            $counter = 0;
        }
    }
?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller(Schedule.php):

```
<?php
class Schedule extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()
        {
                parent::__construct();
                $this->load->model('schedule_model');
                $this->load->helper('url_helper');
        }

        public function index() {
            $data['events'] = $this->schedule_model->get_events();
            $data['title'] = 'Schedule';

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('schedule/index', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

        public function view($slug = NULL) {

            $data['event'] = $this->schedule_model->get_events();

            if (empty($data['events']))
            {
                    show_404();
            }

            $data['title'] = $data['event']['id'];

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('schedule/index', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }

        public function state($slug = NULL) {
            $data['events'] = $this->schedule_model->get_state_events($slug);
            $data['title'] = 'Schedule';

            $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
            $this->load->view('schedule/state', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
}

?>
```

Model(Schedule_model.php):

```
<?php
class Schedule_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
                $this->load->database();
    }

    public function get_events($slug = FALSE) {
        if ($slug === FALSE) {
                $this->db->order_by("start_date", "asc");
                $query = $this->db->get('events');
                return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('events', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

    public function get_state_events($slug = FALSE) {
        if ($slug === FALSE) {
                $this->db->order_by("start_date", "asc");
                $query = $this->db->get('events');
                return $query->result_array();
        }

        $query = $this->db->get_where('events', array('slug' => $slug));
        return $query->row_array();
    }
}

?>
```

Routes:

```
$route['schedule/state/(:any)'] = 'schedule/state/$1';
$route['schedule/state'] = 'schedule/state';
$route['schedule/(:any)'] = 'schedule/view/$1';
$route['schedule'] = 'schedule';
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: try printing the request in the controller and add into the question for that url with id and without id @cameron

Comment: Still same problem. I removed the $slug = NULL argument from state() and hardcoded get_state_events('Utah'), but nothing changed. :-/ @saurabhkamble

Comment: are you saying you are not getting data from the model or its not hitting the controller

Comment: @saurabhkamble It's not passing the data to the foreach() loop on state.php
The /schedule index page works fine, and is identitcal other than the slug. Thanks for your help!

Comment: state.php and index.php are the same. The only difference is that the controller for state() involves a slug, as far as I can tell

Comment: try a `print_r` for `$data['events']` before loading the view and check it there's anything on it. If it's empty, foreaching over it in the view would produce that error. If the array is empty as I suspect, it would mean that the model isn't returning anything (maybe an empty resultset). My suggestion would be to handle this exception in code before returning (i.e. return `false` if the resultset is empty) and then foreach over the array only if `$data['events'] != false`

Comment: If hardcoded get_state_events('Utah') produces the 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'  error then the query produced no results. `$query->row_array()` will return NULL if the `where` condition is not satisfied.

Comment: `$this->db->get_where('events', array('slug' => $slug));`  Is the column in the table actually named "slug"?